# g++ linking error: Undefined reference to a function when the function name is written using #define

Tags: c++, g++

**function.cpp**  -> it is compiled to function.o, then libFunction.so

```
#define PASTEHELPER(a,b) a ## b

#define PASTE(a,b) PASTEHELPER(a,b)

void PASTE(My,Function)() { .... }
```

**main.cpp**  -> compiled to main.o. But error when linking

```
void MyFunction();
```

linking error in g++. (however, successful in Visual Studio)

```
g++ -mtune=i686 -MP -MMD -MT .o -Wextra -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-conversion -Wno-missing-field-initializers -O3 -DNDEBUG -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -fdiagnostics-show-option -DPROJECT=MyProjec  -o /mypath  main.o -L..  -L/sbcimp/run/pd/gcc/32-bit/4.4.2/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.2 -L/sbcimp/run/pd/gcc/32-bit/4.4.2/lib -lFunction -pthread -L/sbcimp/run/pd/python/2.7.1/lib -lpython2.7 -l util  -L/sbcimp/run/pd/boost/32-bit/1.47.0_gcc4.4.2/lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lboost_regex -lboost_system -Wl,-rpath,/sbcimp/run/pd/boost/32-bit/1.47.0_gcc4.4.2/lib -L/sbcimp/run/pd/apache_xerces-c/32-bit/3.1.1_mt_gcc4.4.2/lib -lxerces-c -Wl,-rpath,/sbcimp/run/pd/apache_xerces-c/32-bit/3.1.1_mt_gcc4.4.2/lib -ldl -Wl,-z,origin -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' -Wl,-rpath,/sbcimp/run/pd/gcc/32-bit/4.4.2/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.2,-rpath,/sbcimp/run/pd/gcc/32-bit/4.4.2/lib,-soname,MyProject


main.cpp: undefined reference to 'MyFunction'.
```

The function is not defined in any .h file. Is this the problem? If need to declare the function in .h, how to write it?

Comment: Do you actually compile `function.cpp` as a part of your build in g++? Also, why does your post say that the linker error is reported in the `.h` file? Liker errors are normally reported in `.cpp` files. How do you compile your files in g++?

Comment: Andrey, I correct my question.

Comment: The (rather odd) use of macros is confusing the issue. Can you modify the code in your question so that `function.cpp` just defines `MyFunction` directly, without any use of macros (assuming it still exhibits the problem)? Also, the error message refers to `function.h`, but you haven't shown us that file, or any `#include` directive for it. If you can show us *complete* self-contained code that exhibits the problem, along with the exact g++ command you used and the error message you get, we can help you better.

Comment: there is no function.h. the error is from main.cpp. I modified my question.

Comment: Can you make a minimal but compileable example we can use, and post all the code?

Comment: Where is `function.o` when you link??

Comment: That's not your real code; you would have gotten a syntax error on `....`. You still have the funky macros; can you reproduce the problem without them? That huge `g++` command doesn't refer to `function.cpp` or `main.cpp`; it looks like a link step, and it wouldn't produce an error message referring to `main.cpp`.  *Please* trim your code down to a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the pasted linker error is complete.

But anyway, if the linker really complains about `MyFunction` then it expects the symbol `MyFunction` to be C, not C++ (in C++ it should complain about `MyFunction()`).

So I would guess you're either declaring the `void MyFunction();` as `extern "C"` or you're in fact got `main.o` by compiling `main.c` using `gcc` instead of `main.cpp`.

You can check what you have in the library and what your linker expects by running:

```
objdump -t function.o |grep MyFunction
objdump -t main.o |grep MyFunction
```

If you compiled both .o file from .cpp files, you should get symbol names like `_Z10MyFunctionv`. The symbol name should be the same for both. 
But if one of them is not mangled (ie. is just `MyFunction`), then it's from C, not C++.

If both of them are mangled, but different, then you declared the function differently in both cases.

The use of `#define` shouldn't affect the linker at all.

Comment: I added a declaration "void MyFunction();" in function.h and solved the problem.